# replace-vars in enlive 1.1.4

Tags: clojure, enlive

I have the following html that is loaded into a template...

```
Welcome <b id="alert-username">${fullname}</b>
```

I have the following selector/action in a template...

```
[:#alert-username] (replace-vars {:fullname (fullname request)})
```

This is rendered as follows...

```
 Welcome ${fullname}
```

Which is obviously not what I'm looking for.

However, it works if I do it the hard way...

```
[:#alert-username] (fn [n] (assoc n :content [(fullname request)]))
```

which yields...

```
Welcome Bill
```

So I know that it's not an issue getting the username from the request because the above code does what it should.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `replace-vars` transformation does not recurse into child nodes, including text content.
The selector `:#alert-username` selects the `<b id="alert-username">` tag:

```
{:tag :b, :attrs {:id "alert-username"}, :content ["${fullname}"]}
```

So, `replace-vars`, because it is used on the tag, will search the the tag's attributes and ignore the tag's contents.

You can apply the transform to the contents with something like the following:

```
[:#alert-username] (transform-content
                     (replace-vars {:fullname (fullname request)}))
```

But, that will also search any child tag attributes, along with any child text nodes.

**Note:** The `transform-content` macro is part of the `net.cgrand.enlive-html` namespace.

Comment: Excellent. I knew I had to missing something simple like that.

Comment: I actually think the behavior should be changed to match how you tried to use it. But, I don't know the reasoning behind how it currently functions.

Comment: The readme says, "to replace any ${var} in text and attributes." Which implies that it will work for text children of the node. I think there's at least a case to be made to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a tag enclosing the ${fullname}, you could just use the transform

```
[:#alter-username] (content (fullname request))
```

and put any text in the tag. The content in of the tag given in the the template will be replaced anyway.